# Init table with data works only with breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I initialize table (using this lib [bootstrap-table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/index.html)) with data that I get using ajax.

```
var arr = [];
        var getRows = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: hostUrl,
                contentType: "application/json;",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    arr = result.d;
                }
            });
            return arr; // breakpoint here
        };

$('#bootstrap-table').bootstrapTable({
            data: getRows()
});
```

This code works only if I set breakpoint on return in getRows function. Try to add timeout before return - but this didn't help.

If I don't add breakPoint, I get nothing.

Comment: If you upvoted the `async: false` answer, please undo that vote. That is the worst suggestion anyone can make and should never be encouraged :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ajax call is asynchronous.

arr is returned before the call has returned.

You'd better go with something like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: hostUrl,
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#bootstrap-table').bootstrapTable({
                 data: result.d
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the async parameter in the query

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: hostUrl,
            async: false, //This is the guy you want !!!!!!!!!!!!!
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                arr = result.d;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do not ever use `async: false` as a solution. It causes more problems than it solves. Simply learn how to use async operations the way they were designed.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually better off using promises. Simply return the `$.ajax` promise and handle the data returned external to that function:

```
// GetRows promises to return rows of data...
var getRows = function () {

    // simply return the ajax promise
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: hostUrl,
        contentType: "application/json;",
        dataType: "json",
    });
};
```

And consume like this:

```
// Use the returned promise to process the data
getRows().done(function(rows){
    $('#bootstrap-table').bootstrapTable({
        data: rows
    });
});
```

The problem with callbacks or a `success:` handler is you are building GUI dependencies into the `GetRows` method.